# passing command with ssh to python subprocess to be run in a remote computer/server

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, ssh

I am trying to write python script that will pass the following command to be executed in a particular server.

```
ssh server 'mongo /path/to/file --eval "print('123456\t78');"'
```

The command above is passed to the following function in my script:

```
def runCommand(command):
  process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
  (out,err) = process.communicate()
  return out
```

It turns out, I get the following output:

```
the command: ssh server 'mongo /path/to/file.js --eval "print('123456\t78');"'
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
2016-01-26T09:42:51.084+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

However, when I tried to execute `'mongo /path/to/file.js --eval "print('123456\t78');"'` directly on the server, it works fine as I get the result:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: test
123456  78
test
1
0
```

I suspect, it must has something to do with the (single) quote after `ssh server`. So my question are, how does the best way to pass command with special characters, like quotes or slash, to be run with the ssh command?

Comment: You have inner and outer single quotation marks, that could explain the syntax error.

Comment: @KlausD.Thank you for your response. I see, that is indeed the root of the error. However, how if it has to be passed like that? I mean, with single quote inside the print command.

Comment: Use `\'` for the inner quotations.